# Powershell Direct to Hyper-V Win 10 VM from Jenkins

Tags: virtual-machine, powershell, hyper-v, jenkins, windows-server-2019

I have been trying to use Jenkins to automatically test VMs, which includes copying new code into the VM, or running certain commands from the host into the VM using Powershell Scripts.
However, I've been running into an error trying to using "Invoke-Command" or "New-PSSession" to a hyper-V Windows 10 VM in Jenkins Freestyle and Pipeline projects.

This is the environment Jenkins is running on:

```
Windows Specifications:
Edition: Windows Server 2019 Standard
Version: 1809
OS build: 17763.379
Jenkins ver. 2.190.1
Hyper-V Manager: 10.0.17763.1
```

This is the Powershell Scripts that I've written in a "Windows Powershell" Build Step in a freestyle project:

```
# Win10-Clean is currently running and the credentials are for the Win 10 VM.

$VMName = "Win10-Clean"
$username = "username"
$pwd = "password"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$username", $secpasswd)
Get-VM
Invoke-Command -Credential $mycreds -VMName$VMName -ScriptBlock {host}
```

The output from Jenkins is this:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building on master in workspace G:\ci_server_1\jenkins\workspace\powershell-testing-ground
[powershell-testing-ground] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins6936256398230803297.ps1'"

Name                 State   CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime             Status             Version
----                 -----   ----------- ----------------- ------             ------             -------
Win10-Clean          Running 0           1656              4.12:52:52.1170000 Operating normally 8.3    
An error has occurred which Windows PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (Win10-Clean:String) [], PSRemotingDataStructureException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

After referring to [the official microsoft web page regrding this issue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct), the possible causes are:

1. VM exists but not running
2. Guest OS does not support PowerShell Direct
3. Powershell isn;t avaliable in the guest yet:

   - Operation system hasn't booted yet
   - OS can't boot correctly
   - Some boot time event needs user input
4. A bug in current builds where credentials must be explicitly passed with -Credential. Run Restart-Service -Name vmicvmsession as a work around.

However, from the output from Jenkins, the VM that I've been trying to connect to is "Running" and it is booted up properly.

Then, I've tried to "Invoke-Command" and "New-PSSession" into the VM from the host directly and I am able to connect to the VM.

I've also tried the same thing in a Jenkins installed in a Windows 10 machine instead of a windows server 2019 and everything works.

As for the user administrative information, the user logged in that is running Jenkins is both the "administrator" and the "hyper-v administrator".

These are some of the references I used to debug and I'm not able to find out what the problem is:

1. [Remote Access With PowerShell and Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22437721/11278524), but I'm not able to figure out how exactly this works.
2. [Running Powershell scripts using Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750878)
3. [PowerShell: error executing command using Invoke-Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332286)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

**EDITS:**

I found a way around this issue. Please mind that this isn't the definite solution but a work around.

Instead of running `Invoke-Command -Credential $mycreds -VMName $VMName -ScriptBlock {host}`, run this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "MyHostComputer" -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Command -Credential $mycreds -VMName $VMName -ScriptBlock {host}}
```

This command is essentially `invoke-commanding` into the host machine and use the host machine to run the `Invoke-Command` into the VM.

It is definitely not the perfect solution, but before anyone has a better solution, I'll go with this.

Comment: Have you tested the exact `powershell.exe [...]` command from the jenkins server *as* the jenkins user? I found other people with this exact error, but it was always transient and usually went away after the remote VM restarted etc.

Comment: @user19702 Do you mean running for instance `powershell.exe [Invoke-Command -Credential $mycreds -VMName $VMName -ScriptBlock {host}]` in the `Windows PowerShell` build environment? And I've tried restarting the VMs and it doesn't seem to fix it. I've been constantly running into this problem. Doesn't seem transient to me.

Comment: Try the full script call `powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\[...]` as your jenkins user from your jenkins server to get the most accurate environment.

Comment: You may want to view the difference between your environments (since it works for your user) by writing `Get-ChildItem env: | Export-CliXml ./env-vars.clixml` to a file and comparing between users.

Comment: @user19702 I found out that the users used by the host and Jenkins are different. By running this command: `$Current_name = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name`, jenkins gives me `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, and my host gives me this: `MYSERVER1\Administrator`. Also, `$env:UserDomain/$env:Username` on jenkins gives me this: `DIR/MYSERVER1$` and my host gives me this: `MYSERVER1\Administrator`. Is this the cause of the problem? If so, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @user19702 I've also added the additional line `powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass` without the `"& 'C:\[...]` since it could find the file. It is still giving me the same error

Comment: Are you specifying the remote computer as the domain for the user? eg `$username = "MyVM1\Administrator"`? Also: Try using the `-computername` flag instead of `-vmname` since I can't rule out any hyper-v weirdness. This requires your VM to have some networking configured.

Comment: @user19702 In terms of specifying the remote computer as the domain for the user, no, I am not using it. For now, I'm using the username "username" of the VM. I will need to investigate the use of the `-computername`.

Comment: @user19702 I actually found a way around this issue. If I `Invoke-Command` to my host machine and then run the `Invoke-command` into the VM using `-ScruptBlock`, it works.